# position sticky not working properly with Direction RTL on Iphone

Tags: html, css, sass

im facing an issue with position sticky on direction RTL html, I have a table in which the first `td` of the `thead` and `tbody` have position sticky with `right: 0;`, on `scroll x,` the table parent container has `overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: auto; white-space: nowrap;`!! everything works fine even on chrome dev tools, firefox, and also codepen its working, but when I open the same thing on my **iphone** the position sticky is stuck to the left, like this, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AdaT.jpg) but the left side looks like this, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7li8i.jpg), also when the scroll x-direction happens the sticky elements diasporas and comes back non stop, anyone knows why?
thank you.
codepen - https://codepen.io/shammlo/pen/rNMeZNe?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

Safari (on all platforms) has always glitched when using `position:sticky` with `right` or `left` in RTL reading direction. I am not aware of any open WebKit bug for this or any plan to address the issue. I suggest you open a WebKit bug, and for the foreseeable future, not use sticky in this way for RTL direction.